# widget on focus show list and remove list

Tags: jquery, html, css, widget

i had a widget which is a wrapper of a input and button. i want to dispaly the dropdown on both input focus and button click. It works fine on button click and input works fine only one time after that not working. Even if u select an option its not working....If u make input blur then it will work fine, until u select something or use button click.... below is my code .....any work around plz.................................

```
  input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .attr("title", "")
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    appendTo: wrapper,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                        response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                return {
                                    label: text,
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }));

                    },

                .focus(function () {                    
                    $(".ui-combobox").addClass("focus");                    

                    if (wasOpen) {
                        return;
                    }

                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                })

                .blur(function () {                 
                    $(".ui-combobox").removeClass("focus");
                });

            // creating the anchor button
            $("<button></button>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .addClass("br-r")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .mousedown(function () {
                    wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
                })
                .click(function () {
                    input.focus();

                    if (wasOpen) {
                        return;
                    }

                    input.autocomplete("search", "");                   
                });
        },
```

the above is just the snippet deals with the required functionality.........

Comment: you didnt put one period in your sentence. i don't understand when it works and when it doesn't.

Comment: Where is your html code? Can you show us that?

Comment: @btevfik , have a look now sorry for the previous copy ...

Comment: can you put an alert() only, after  `.focus(function () {` and see if it firing multiple times?

Comment: i think you need to close autocomplete and then add focus  `}).focus(function ()` like this

Comment: yes it is do u think using off may fix this...

Comment: how about blur? does that fire multiple times too. it just seems like there is a problem with where you are assigning the functions

Comment: i had closed auto complte even though its the same

Comment: i think this is actually what you want to do    `}})

                .focus(function () {     `

Answer (score 0):

try this for the input

```
input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .attr("title", "")
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    appendTo: wrapper,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

                        response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                return {
                                    label: text,
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }));

                    }})

                .focus(function () {                    
                    $(".ui-combobox").addClass("focus");                    

                    if (wasOpen) {
                        return;
                    }

                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                })

                .blur(function () {                 
                    $(".ui-combobox").removeClass("focus");
                });
```